What are some options to test ARM assembly that some compiler outputs under Windows? QEMU is not an option, right?
So, I've designed a programming language called AEC and I've made an AEC-to-x86 compiler and an AEC-to-WebAssembly compiler. I am thinking about developing an AEC-to-ARM compiler.
A little problem is: how can I test the assembly code my AEC-to-ARM compiler outputs if I am working under Windows? Under Linux, QEMU can run both virtual machines running OS-es and user-space apps for various architectures. But, under Windows, QEMU can only run virtual machines. So, how can that problem be addressed? Is there some alternative to QEMU which works under Windows? Or is the best thing to do to develop the compiler targetting ARM under Linux, rather than under Windows?

Set up the VM. https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-Emulator-for-Windows-10/ Or get a low-end Raspberry Pi or similar. Depending on the code you're generating (e.g., 32- or 64-bit) you may be able to test with something like a Raspberry Pi Zero that sells for $5.

There is no Windows for ARM, so whatever you do, you'll need to use/target a non-windows OS for ARM.

@ChrisDodd: "There is no Windows for ARM" Yes there is.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/arm/overview

It may also be worth nothing that most Android development tool sets include ARM emulators.
